# How to user route model binding in Laravel for Pivot model

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, pivot-table, php-7.2

Laravel v: 5.7

PHP v: 7.2.10

Route path is: `admin/apartments/{apartment}/associations/{association}/association-users/{association_user}`
Getting URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/apartments/1/associations/1/association-users`

Pivot Model: `AssociationUser`

In `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`, I have added

```
public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        Route::bind('association-user', function ($value) {
            return App\pivotes\AssociationUser::where('association_id', request()->route()->parameter('association')->id)->where('user_id', auth()->id())->first() ?? abort(404);
        });
    }
```

Route Creation

```
route('apartments.associations.association-users.show', ['apartment' => $associationUser->association->apartment, 'association' => $associationUser->association, 'association_user' => $associationUser ])
```

Comment: What is the problem, you always get 404?

Comment: @thefallen  I am gettinng the index page and not the show page, you can see I am missing the model there.

Comment: I would instead move this logic into a middleware or in the controller method, because with route binding this thing is hidden and is like magic, but the bad kind of it.

Comment: @thefallen what will be the proper way to get route model binding for pivote models?

Comment: You just bind it to the correct model class and in the middleware or controller you validate that they have a relation between each other.

Comment: @thefallen I have done it in controller like `public function show(Apartment $apartment, Association $association, AssociationUser $associationUser) ` but it does not seems to be working, it will a great help, if you can give me some link or provit a minimal snipet to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong association_user pivot table should have association_id and user_id and combination of both will be unique, so in your route there is already `{association}` model, so I believe you can use

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'user_id';
}
```

in you pivot model class so that user_id will come in your url and you will be having combination of association and user model.

You **do not need**

```
 Route::bind('association-user', function ($value) {
            return App\pivotes\AssociationUser::where('association_id', request()->route()->parameter('association')->id)->where('user_id', auth()->id())->first() ?? abort(404);
        });
```

in your `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`

Comment: This will not work when you have the same user_id multiple times in the pivot table. So if you have a record with association_id: 1 and user_id: 8 and a record with association_id: 2 and user_id: 8 you will get the wrong record if you have a route with association 2 and user 8. It will give you the record with association 1 and user 8, since that will bethe first record where user_id is 8.